# Edit Azure function (Python) in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I'm new to using Azure function apps and need to publish an updated init.py file to an existing function app.

Since Download app content is missing and I'll need to recreate it locally, what is normally contained in this file?

Is it possible to make sure all of the original settings remain the same and only update the init.py file?

Comment: Hi cheeriepie, may I know if your problem was solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this requirement, I think you just need to copy the init.py code from azure to your new function in local VS code and copy the function.json from azure to local VS code.

In the new function you created in VS code, you need to use the init.py code and function.json copied above. And you need to run the command `pip freeze > requirements.txt` in "TERMINAL" in VS code to generate a `requirements.txt` which contains all of the pip modules used in your new function.

Then you can deploy it from VS code to Azure, the init.py(local) will cover the init.py in Azure and the function.json(local) will also cover the function.json in Azure. The new function in Azure will rebuild(install the pip modules) according to the requirements.txt you generated just now.

You can run this command in "TERMINAL" in VS code to deploy your new function from local to azure.

```
func azure functionapp publish hurypyfunapp --build remote
```

The new function you deployed from local to azure will not affect other settings such as "Application settings" and so on.

By the way, before the deployment, you can test your function locally by running the command below in "TERMINAL" in VS code to start your function.

```
func host start
```

Hope it helps~

Comment: Hi @HuryShen, your solution worked great! I really appreciate your help and guidance. I ended up using 'Deploy to Function App...' (blue up arrow) in VS code Azure extension to deploy since I hit a permission denied error when I used the recommended command. Thanks again!